# New line \n characters are missing when data sent through djnago restframework Response using model as dictionay

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am sending the data model which has TextField , all the '\n' characters are missing when i receive it in the browser. 
And not able to put it in the paragraph as same as database format.
It is shown in both database and django shell. but not in the HTML response.
I am trying to show a blog content in angular component.

I have tried json.dumps to convert it into a string of json,

I have a TextFeild in django model , with another foreign key as author,
I need to display the content as it written by the user.

Comment: A `\n` in HTML will not be displayed as a line feed. You will have to use `<br>` or block tags of any kind.

Comment: Please show example of original text and the _broken_ response.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with DRF.

Comment: Try rendering the field inside a <pre> tag

Comment: As you said, I tried <br>, but I saw that was supposed to be done in the server itself _content.replace('\n',<br>)_, and i add the text using [innerHtml] in angular, which worked fine. Thanks.